# I want to make a download section

Tags: node.js

I created a function which allows me to download a PDF, but it is not working.

Here is my function:

```
exports.getDownloadPdf =  (res,req,next) => {
const invoiceName = 'fw9' + '.pdf';
const invoicePath = path.join('data', 'invoices', invoiceName);
fs.readFile(invoicePath, (err, data) => {
if(err) {
 return next(err);
}
res.send(data);
});
}
```

My link

```
 <a href="/downloadPDF">Download here</a>
```

And my route

```
router.get('/downloadPDF',isAuth, feedController.getDownloadPdf);
```

I expected to download the pdf, but it throws me

```
TypeError: res.send is not a function
```

If you can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Express [res.download](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download) helper:

```
app.get('/downloadPDF', function(req, res){
    const invoiceName = 'fw9' + '.pdf';
    const invoicePath = path.join('data', 'invoices', invoiceName);
    res.download(invoicePath);
});
```

Let me know if that helped you solve this

Comment: @CalinOnaca - The first param should be `req` not `res`. In your callback it is `function(res, req, next)`. Make sure its in the correct order according to [Express API](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html)